# fill hidden filed value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function called makehash()
I have to fill the value of hash field with the return value of makehash()

```
<form action="http://example.com/test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
<input type="hidden" name="upload_mode" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.forms[0].elements["hash"].value = makehash();
```

This assumes you have only one form, if you have more specify the form name instead of 0 or give ID to the hidden input and use `document.getElementById` instead.

Comment: This assumes the element is in the first form, be sure to check where it is :)

Comment: thanks for reply, I have added the entire form in the main question .

Comment: @Krishna my answer is still the same.. that line of code, placed at bottom of page, will populate your hidden field with the return value of the function `makehash`.

Comment: I have added it in   <script type="text/javascript"> tags ..but its not populating the form..I checked the source code after opening in browser..the value is not filled..its empty..just to test if the function is working or not , I checked alert(makehash()) , so the function is working fine..

Comment: @Krishna - you won't see it in source code, change it to `<input type="text" name="hash" value="">` and you should see it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I want it to be hidden .. is it possible to do it like that ?

Comment: @Krishna - sure, just change it for the sake of debug. If you see the return value of the function called `makehash` appear inside the text box then it proves the code is working and afterwards have the type `hidden` again. The type of input is not relevant for its value, you can read the value using server side code when the form is being submitted. If you need help with that let us know what server side language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by grabbing the input ([`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName)) and setting the [`.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Input),  like this:

```
document.getElementsByName("hash")[0].value = makehash();
```

There are other ways as well, if it's unique an `id` is a good option for example.

Comment: getElementsByName is not cross browser as far as I know.. what browsers support it?

Comment: @Shadow - All browsers support it well enough for this, IE and Opera have trouble in some rarer cases.

Comment: thanks, I've now found the the problem is only when giving name to elements such as `div` which is not relevant for this case. :)